# distance from top of element to top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I figure out the distance from the top of an element to the top of the window. By window I mean viewport not document? And not on page render, currently.

`$(element).offset().top;` seems too large and so does `$(element).position.top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$(element).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()
```